# If statement within template to correctly assign thumbnail and actual size image for use with Fancybox

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, fancybox

Friends,

Within my Django template I am using the following code to display my images:

```
<article id="originalexample_photos">
   <table>    
      <tr> 
         {% for photo in photos %}      
            <img src="{{ photo.photo.url }}"/>
         {% endfor %}
      </tr>
   </table>
</article>
```

This works ok but now I would like to use Fancybox to display a thumbnail and when clicked the actual size image.

The `photos` dictionary contains both the thumbnail and actual size image. I can obtain the output I want with the following hardcoded example.

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="IMGP0058_big.jpg"><img src="IMGP0058_small.jpg" alt="Demo1" /></a>
```

Each thumbnail will be called something_small.jpg and the actual size images will be called something_big.jpg

So to I think I need some form of `IF statement` to put the images in the correct position within the Fancybox anchor but none of the examples of the `IF statement` I have seen in the Django documentation have come near to what I what to achieve. Which has set of alarm bells in case I have gone down the wrong path!

Any help with constructing the `IF statement` or a better method would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

What I would like to achieve is shown by the Fancybox demo [Simple image gallery](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/)

**Update 2**

Here is the first output using JFK's answer.

```
     <script>
       var group = [];
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#originalexample_photos").find("img").each(function (i) {
            var src = $(this).attr("src").split("_");
            var href = src[0] + "_big.jpg";
            var title = $(this).attr("alt");
            group[i] = {href: href, title: title};
            $(this).on("click", function(){
                $.fancybox(group,{
                    index: i
                }); // fancybox
            }); // on
        }); // each
    }); // ready
   </script>

   <article id="originalexample_photos">
      <table>    
         <tr> 
            <img src="/media/images/IMGP0058_small.jpg"/>                   
            <img src="/media/images/IMGP0058_big.jpg"/>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </article>
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no need for if or anything else, just use a thumbnail library such as sorl or easy thumbnail and you should be ok, unless you want to re-invent the wheel and create your own.

Comment: do you mean: (1) click on page thumbnail opens same thumbnail in fancybox, then clicking such thumbnail (in fancybox) opens the the big image still inside fancybox? -- or -- (2) click thumbnail image (as in your template) open the big image in fancybox (without changing the template as in the hard-code example) ... or else?

Comment: BTW, if more than one image, should they belong to a fancybox image gallery?

Comment: @JFK: Thanks for taking the time to comment, I've updated my answer to include the desired output. On the Fancybox demo page, it's the first example shown. Apologies I don't understand your BTW.

Comment: What you would like to achieve has coded anchors but your django template doesn't. I think you can achieve the same result without actually changing the template and without any `IF` statement (and without actually any anchors if your image names follow a patterns e.g. `something_small.jpg` and `something_big.jpg`) ... I will post an answer

Comment: @JFK: Brilliant thanks, the images will follow that naming format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sorl-thumbnail

In your settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'sorl.thumbnail'
    ...
)
```

After that make sure you:

If you are not using south:

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

If you are using south:

```
./manage.py schemamigration --initial thumbnail
```

Then migrate accordingly.

In your template:

```
{% load thumbnail %}
```

And then within your block of interest:

```
{% thumbnail photo.photo "800x600" as im %}
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="{{ photo.photo.url }}"><img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="Demo1" /></a> 
{% endthumbnail %}
```

You will find more information in the official documentation:
http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for the response, got this working tonight within 5 minutes. Brilliant. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If your images are following a pattern like :

```
something01_small.jpg (thumbnail)
something01_big.jpg (actual size)

something02_small.jpg (thumbnail)
something02_big.jpg (actual size)

... etc.
```

then I think you can achieve what you want without changing your *django* template and without any `IF` statement.

So having displayed your image thumbnails only, you could use a simple jQuery initialization like :

```
var group = [];
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#originalexample_photos").find("img").each(function (i) {
        var src = $(this).attr("src").split("_");
        var href = src[0] + "_big.jpg";
        var title = $(this).attr("alt");
        group[i] = {href: href, title: title};
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            $.fancybox(group,{
                index: i
            }); // fancybox
        }); // on
    }); // each
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0jxdb1n4/)**

Comment: So close to perfection, the only issue is that both the thumbnail and actual size images are shown on the page. It will be a good learning lesson for me to work how to stop the bigger image appearing. Thanks again.

Comment: @IanCarpenter : do you mean your django template is showing both on the html document?

Comment: Yes I do. I will update my question to show the source of the html

Comment: @IanCarpenter : I am afraid I am not a django expert to say how to filter the thumbnails only within the loop (I could tell you how to remove them with jQuery though)

Comment: No worries, you've got me 99% of the way which I am very grateful for. I will update my question once I have it working. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Couldn't "do" the last 1% so have used petkostas solution